# Disable interaction on subview of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom table cell with two subView in it. One of them should allow user interaction, and one of the views should not allow interaction.

I have already tried userInteraction enable and disable on UIView but didn't get any result.

[image]

```
 @IBOutlet weak var headerView: UIView!
 @IBOutlet weak var detailView: UIView!
```

The orange selected color is my **detailView** and i want to prevent user interaction on this view.

Comment: what kind of interaction do you mean? didSelectCell or UITapGesture or others?

Comment: @aiwiguna I don't want any kind of interaction on my orange selected color View(detail view) when the user taps on it.

Comment: I still missed something here, isn't by default UIView did not have any user interaction? so I don't know what kind of interaction you have right now with your detailview, maybe you can share your tableview code

Comment: @aiwiguna, Yes UIView by default have interaction but if i disable it doesn't work. Only i can disable the full cell interaction but not that specific view(DetailView) of the cell.

Comment: what kind of user interaction that happens right now that you want to disable?

Comment: Then you can remove your code from `didSelectRowAt` and add a gesture on your view that you want to have an interaction. Use some callback/delegate to execute your code removed from `didSelectRowAt`.

Comment: @aiwiguna , Link - https://github.com/tadija/AEAccordion ,  i am using this library, you can see the code from here. I don't want any user-interaction on the details view (expanded view), i need it only in the header view where the user tapped first. Thank you.

Comment: @MdRashedPervez what happens when you tap detailview right now? you not answering the question with link to library you used, because if the interaction is didSelectRowAt you need to change that like Kamran said

Comment: @aiwiguna At present when i tap on the detail view it's hiding under the header view, this action needed to be removed, the details view will stood stand even after the tap on it. And i have already done what kamran said but no luck.

Comment: you need to share a minimal reproduceable code so someone can reproduce your problem and help https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example